# Large Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have approximately `< 1300` arrays in a list. Number of arrays is expected to grow in the future

This is how I list them:

```
var listofarrays{
 listone:['string element', 'another string element'],
 listtwo:['string element', 'another string element'],
 listhree:['string element', 'another string element'],
 listfour:['string element', 'another string element']
// ... and so on ... the lists over contain a lot of arrays.
//I figured it was best to not copy/paste it all.
};
```

My questions are:

1. Can there be any problem on adding more arrays?
2. How can I use minimum storage to save all these arrays?

Comment: Why would you not use arrays of arrays?  Or are your arrays not really called `listone`, `listtwo`, etc.?

Comment: Maybe [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays)

Comment: @Brad No, they are just to show it as an example. 'arrays here' represents that I have like a large quantity of arrays here. I figured that was better than copy pasting everything.

Comment: @user1431627, Now I'm really confused.  Names aside, in your example is `listofarrays.listone` supposed to be an array of strings?  Or an array of arrays?  You say `"arrays here"`... but is that an element of the array, or supposed to be shorthand for an array itself?

Comment: @Brad Edited. Hope you understand now. listone, listtwo etc. are arrays, inside them are strings :)

Comment: Computers are designed to handle the level of scale that people can't. As long as you don't exceed the available RAM, go for it!

Comment: @user1431627, What you say in your comment and what you have in your post doesn't totally line up, but I think I see what you are getting at.  I will edit your post to make it more clear for others.  If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @Brad I am pretty new to JavaScript. What I understand this is: 'listofarrays' is a Object. Inside we have listone, listtwo etc and they are arrays containing strings. Is this right?

Comment: @user1431627, That is correct.  I think earlier you were confusing elements with arrays themselves.

Comment: Can we get a little more info on what this is for? Are all the arrays unique? I'm looking for ways to compress your object but if each array in that object is necessary, I don't truly see a way to reduce it :/... there aren't many data structures available in Javascript from my understanding but I could be wrong.

Comment: @aug They are pretty unique. The lists are basically names.

Answer (score 0):

1. Adding = Slower performance.
2. How to solve it? I would recommend to load the required data using AJAX.

I put example for better visualization JQuery Autocomplete:

- Old way: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default
- AJAX way: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Hope helps
:)

Comment: It is an idea, but it will add an increase in bad performance when loading up new arrays.